# MySQL 8 create new user with password not working

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using MySQL for several years and the command for the creating the new user till the MySQL 5.x version is as follow:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Recently I installed the MySQL 8. In that, this command is not working.

It is throwing following error while firing above command:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'password'' at line 1
```

Is there any change of syntax in MySQL 8? What is the correct syntax for creating new user command in MySQL 8?

Note: I tried this syntax in MySQL 5.x versions. It is working correctly in that.

Comment: The manual page for [5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) says: *Use of GRANT to define account authentication characteristics is deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.6. Instead, establish or change authentication characteristics using CREATE USER or ALTER USER. This GRANT capability will be removed in a future MySQL release.*

Comment: The correct command for creating a user in MySQL 8 is [CREATE USER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html). Apparently the option to create the user when granting privileges has been removed - see [GRANT syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html). Best of luck.

Comment: Good question, and good answers. And still, why deprecate this? Make everybody waste time, and change their scripts just because the new syntax is "cleaner"? Hmm.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Try this:

```
use mysql;
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
flush privileges;
```

Comment: I actually had to do `'root'@'rhel'` where `'rhel'` was my hostname

Comment: 'flush privileges' is not needed when working with `CREATE USER` and 'GRANT`

Comment: When running the line that begins with GRANT ALL, I get this error: "ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT."  Despite the fact that I literally just created the user using the CREATE USER command.

Answer (score 7):

From MySQL recent releases -

To create a user -

```
CREATE USER 'newuser1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'Password@123';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'newuser1'@'localhost';
```

This is two lines code to create a new user, and granting permissions.

Worked with MySQL Community server version `8.0.26` windows 10 x64 bit server.